# Getting number of rows using Left Join kql? Function 'row_number' cannot be invoked in current context. Details: the row set must be serialized

Tags: row-number, azure-log-analytics, kql

I have the following query:

```
let p1 = pageViews | where url has "xxx";
p1
| join kind=inner (pageViews 
        | where  url !has "xxx")
on session_Id
| project timestamp1, session_Id1, url1, client_CountryOrRegion1, client_StateOrProvince1, client_City1, user_Id1
```

It does get users that originated from a certain provider and then looks at which URLs they are going to.

I am now trying to get how many users I got from that provider.

I could just do `distinct session_Id` and `count` but what I would like to do is add two columns, first for specific session_id and then increment it when it changes and another one to increment for the number of requests made.

i.e

[image]

I [tried](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/data-explorer/kusto/query/rownumberfunction):

```
 let p1 = pageViews | where url has "project-management";
p1
| join kind=inner (pageViews 
        | where  url !has "project-management")
on session_Id
| project timestamp1, session_Id1, url1, client_CountryOrRegion1, client_StateOrProvince1, client_City1, user_Id1 
| extend Rank=row_number(1)
```

but it gave me

> Function 'row_number' cannot be invoked in current context. Details: the row set must be serialized

Answer (score 7, accepted):

The records in the output aren't sorted, therefore there's no meaning to `row_number()`.

`row_number()` only works on serialized records, which you have after using `order by`, or `serialize`.

So the solution to your question is to add `| serialize` before `| extend Rank=row_number(1)`.